# node pointing to itself

Tags: c++, linked-list

```
struct node
{
    node(int val,node * a = NULL,node*b= NULL):previous(a),next(b),value(val){}
    ~node(){cout << "value " << value << " is being freed\n";}
    node * previous;
    node * next;
    int value;
} ;

int main()
{

 node * some;
 some = new node(10,some,some);

 cout << some->next->value << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Why does this simple code fail to print out ten? `some->next` should resolve to the address of `some` which should have access to value. What am I missing? Maybe during construction of the object it fails to properly assign value of `some`? It outputs -1916565246 which looks like an address.

Comment: What does it actually output?

Comment: `some` isn't initialised when you're passing it in as an argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're passing `some` into the constructor, it is not initialised yet. It will only be initialised to the value returned from `new` after the constructor exits.

An unitialised variable in C++ has indeterminate value, and reading from it is undefined. You're most likely seeing the contents of memory which happened to be in the space reserved for `some`.

Comment: I'd +1 this if you gave a quick mention to 'junk' and why he's seeing a number like that.

Answer (score 2):

`It outputs -1916565246 which looks like an address.`
It is not an address. Note that when `some` is passed to the constructor, it had some garbage value, say 'g'. Now previous and next are assigned 'g', and what you are looking at is the content stored at 'g'. As we know, pointers have no default value. Thus, 'g' might not be a legal address and this could segfault as well.

I have learned to observe the practice of initializing all pointers to `NULL` from similar (bad) experiences.

It is worth mentioning here that you could actually have used your compiler to point you to the trouble.
Just compile using the option `-Wall`

```
axiom@a1:~/MultirExperiments$ g++ t.cpp -Wall
t.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
t.cpp:16:30: warning: ‘some’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
```

Comment: You can actually add to another answer yourself. It's better than posting a partial answer.

Comment: @DonReba Right, but I had more to say. Change of plans.

Comment: **+1** for `-Wall` kicking and screaming. This is reason 584 why you should always compile with `-Wall`.